# digifoto wordpress theme - portfolio not found?

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I'm building a photography portfolio for a client using the digifoto theme. When I try making a portfolio, it comes up in the gallery page, but when I click to see the photos in it, it says "Not Found - page being requested could not be found".
I'm clicking into the portfolio tab, making a new one, titling it and inserting photos, then the details in the correct fields, I create the "post" (portfolio), but I can't preview it (I got the 'not found' error) and I can't see it as a published thing anyway.
It seems like there's no documentation on the Digifoto theme (how to use it). Any WP experts here that can help?

Comment: did you have any luck with the rest of the theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a Permalink problem. It often happens when you register custom post type (portfolio in your case) and the link goes 404. Try saving the permalink structure once again and it will work.

Permalink Settings:

- Navigate to ***Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks***

Comment: After I installed the new WP version, it seemed to work, you might be right though... Thanks!